# Loading timestamps in sybase iq using bcp

Tags: sql, sybase, bcp, sap-iq

Is there a way I can load timestamp data into my sybase table using `LOAD TABLE` (BCP) query?

ex: I want to load timestamp of this format `[2000/01/01:12:00:00 AM]` using `LOAD TABLE`, and it is throwing error:

> cannot convert to Timestamp

Comment: Do you really need a `timestamp` format? Can you use `datetime`?

Comment: @daria both are same.. Aren't they?